# Learning to write to an array in Cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

The simplified code of what I am tyring to do is much slower when I write to the "a" array:

in the pyx file:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def writearray(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] a):

   cdef int i,j,k,l
   cdef DTYPE_t sum=0.0

   for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        for k in range(100):
            for l in range(1000):
                sum+=1.0
            a[0]+=sum #this is the trouble line that makes the code slow.
```

I thought I have "a[0]" and "sum" to be the same type, but do I?
Before this function is called, the "a" array is declared as

```
a=np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float64)
```

Analyzing "a[0]+=sum" using "cython -a" shows (no yellow):

```
   __pyx_t_5 = 0;
   *__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(__pyx_t_11kobpairwise_DTYPE_t *,      
   __pyx_pybuffernd_a.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_5, 
   __pyx_pybuffernd_a.diminfo[0].strides) += __pyx_v_sum;
```

Thanks in advance.

This problem is much more simplified than the full problem in which the index of a depends on all i,j,k,l and sum is no longer incremented by a constant, so I need to find out the root cause of this problem instead of moving a[0] out of the loops, etc.

Comment: Please compile with `cython -a`, then show us the C code that the `a[0] += sum` line turns into.  You should get an HTML file in the same directory as the PYX.  Click on the offending line and it will expand into the translated C.

Comment: There is no yellow:

a[0]+=sum 
        __pyx_t_5 = 0;
        *__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(__pyx_t_11kobpairwise_DTYPE_t *, __pyx_pybuffernd_a.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_5, __pyx_pybuffernd_a.diminfo[0].strides) += __pyx_v_sum;
      }
    }
  }

Comment: It's difficult to be sure.  I'm going to guess that `sum` is living in a register and that `a[0]` isn't.  That means the latter requires an extra load/store each iteration.  It's also possible that macro is not optimized as well as Cython is assuming.  You might have better luck if you just add `sum` to `a[0]` once at the end of the whole function.

Comment: You might get some small benefit from changing the declaration of `a` to `np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1,mode="c"]`. This tells Cython that the array is C-continuous (i.e. it can ignore strides) which is true in your case.

Comment: Maybe when you remove the `a[0]+=sum` the C compiler is able to optimize out a lot -if not all- of the looping. This is a common pitfall when micro-benchmarking compiled code.

Comment: @RyanC.Robinson how is the index to your array `a` built based on the indices `i,j,k,l`? It seems you could change the order of your loops to avoid big strides and cache losses...

Answer (score 0):

You say that a[0] += sum is the trouble line that makes the code slow.  How did you determine this?  There's precious little information about just how fast or slow it is.  Does it take 10% longer or 1000% longer than if you comment it out?

### Here's a theory

Given that the real situation you're talking about involves a lot of other variables that determine the index into a, I'd suspect that it's simply not in the cache and has to be fetched every single time.  Everything else goes fast because it's predictable (stepping through the array linearly), but if a is big enough (many thousands of entries) and you're indexing into it randomly, well, it might not fit into cache along with everything else that's going on.

So it's not that a[0] += sum is slow.  That's fast.  The math is definitely fast.  And the predictable index is fast too.

It's that a[random_index] is slow to load, because it's not in the cache, because the difference between the current random_index and the last random_index is usually large, and so everything that the CPU would normally do to hide some or most of this latency for you falls flat.